# save created product in session and assign to customer after guest logged in

Tags: magento-1.8, product, image, controllers, session

once guest user click on button "create",

1) we are creating product programatically and

2) displaying pop up form to enter email id , password and login button.

[image]

once click on login button, we are creating new product and assiging that to customer [ as guest will become customer after login ]

what i want to know is once guest user click on "create" button, as we create product programtically, can we keep that product in session or in somewhere and once guest click on login button, can we assign that product to customer ?

is this possible to achieve ?

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }

            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }                  

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

                    //images
                    $images = array(
                            'image' => 'image.png'                    

                    );

                    foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
                        if ($newImagePath != "") {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                            $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                        } else {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                        }
                        //echo $path."<br>";
                        if (file_exists($path)) {
                            try {
                                       if ($imageType == 'image' && $newImagePath) {
                                             Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNewImagePath($path);
                                             }
                                          $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                                        }   
                            catch (Exception $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
                        }
                    }


                    //$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    //  $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

                    $newImagePath = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNewImagePath();

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();
                    // To save inside my_designs table

                    $data  = array(
                        'title' => fav1_id,
                        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                        'customer_id' => $customerId,
                        'store_id' => 1,
                        'created_at' => $emaildate,
                        'value' => $newImagePath

                    );
                    $model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
                    try {
                        $fav1_id = $model->save()->getId();
                        //echo "Custom Design saved successfully";
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    // To save inside my_designs end

                    return $product;

                    // code for guest                

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();

                }

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an observer for customer_register_success event and create the product there.

Comment: can you please help me with code........

Comment: check the code here. https://github.com/bgkavinga/sample-code/raw/master/new-cusomer-product.tar.gz I haven't tested it.

Comment: i tried , but it didt worked for me....

Comment: What you want is to create a new product for newly registered customers? Am I right?

Comment: once guest click on `create button` ,  We are creating new product... than we click on `login` button, it will display `pop up` , in that we will enter email id and pw and click on login button, than guest will become registered user. for that user we need to assign the product when we created after click on `create` button....

Comment: Why do you want to create the product when guest click on create the button? Instead, you can create the product first time they logged in.

Comment: yes , when guest click on `create` buttton, we dont need the product , we need only when they click on login button....

Comment: product which created  for `create` button custom image is assigning, but not for `login` button. so only we are planning to save the product which is created by `create` button in `session` and than we want to assign the product to guest once they logged in , please guide me for this, i am really struggling from 3 months for this......

Comment: inititally i tried like [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170883/assign-a-custom-image-to-product-created-programmatically-magento-1-8) , but i failed to achieve that, so i am trying this way.....

Comment: It is confusing. Could you please explain your requirement? without the way, you are trying to implement it.